# Saving Applicant model in database fails, why?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a django web app which requires users to be able to apply for jobs.

Here is the relevant model for the applicant:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       # So that the same user can't apply to the same job twice.
       unique_together = [("job", "user"),]
```

Here is the view using this model to create and save an applicant:

```
@login_required
def job_apply(request, job_pk):
    # Get the job that the user has applied for.
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_pk)
    applicant = models.Applicant(job=job, user=request.user)
    applicant.save()
    return reverse('jobs:find')
```

This is the error message that django gives me:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Does the stack trace tell you where that error occurs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`job_apply` is a view. The contract for a view is that it accepts a request and returns a response. But you are not returning a response: you're just returning a path, which is the result of `reverse`.

You should use `redirect` instead, as that is a shortcut that creates a response that is a redirect to the named URL.

```
return redirect('jobs:find')
```